# Valor index não está sendo reconhecido corretamente

Tags: jquery, html, índices

Tenho o seguinte código `jQuery`:

```
$('.dock-a').hide();
$('.dock').each(function(){
    var DOCK = $(this);
    DOCK.click(function(){
        var DOCK_largura = $(window).width(),
            DOCK_index = $(this).index(),
            DOCK_content = $('.dock-content:eq('+DOCK_index+')'),
            DOCK_a = $('.dock-a:eq('+DOCK_index+')');
        beforeClick = $(window).scrollTop();

        DOCK_content.animate({ 'width': DOCK_largura+'px' }, 500);
        DOCK_a.delay(500).show().animate({ 'opacity':'1' }, 300);
        DOCK_content.delay(400).animate({ 'height': DOCK_a.outerHeight(true)+'px' }, 200);      
    });
});
```

A finalidade dele é: quando alguém clicar em um `link` com a classe `.dock`, ele abre um conteúdo em cima da página atual, semelhante a uma `shadowbox`. O problema é que somente o primeiro link funciona, acredito que está dando alguma falha em obter o valor `index` de cada elemento sequencial.

No `HTML` está assim:

```
<div class="link">
   <div class="box">
      <a href="#" class="dock">Um</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="link">
   <div class="box">
      <a href="#" class="dock">Dois</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="link">
   <div class="box">
      <a href="#" class="dock">Três</a>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="dock-content">
   <div class="dock-a">
      Texto do link Um.
   </div>
</div>
<div class="dock-content">
   <div class="dock-a">
      Texto do link Doi.
   </div>
</div>
<div class="dock-content">
   <div class="dock-a">
      Texto do link Três.
   </div>
</div>
```

Testei um `script` simples em um arquivo á parte, com a mesma funcionalidade e deu certo. Provavelmente é o valor `index` que está dando erro, mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `.index()` retorna o índice do elemento pedido **em relação ao elemento pai**. No seu caso, todos os links terão índice zero. Acho que você quer o índice do elemento `.link` que contém o link, certo? Nesse caso, pode fazer assim:

```
$('.dock-a').hide();
$('.dock').each(function(){
    var DOCK = $(this);
    DOCK.click(function(){
        var DOCK_largura = $(window).width(),
            DOCK_index = $(this).closest('.link').index(), // <--- mudança aqui
            DOCK_content = $('.dock-content:eq('+DOCK_index+')'),
            DOCK_a = $('.dock-a:eq('+DOCK_index+')');
        beforeClick = $(window).scrollTop();

        DOCK_content.animate({ 'width': DOCK_largura+'px' }, 500);
        DOCK_a.delay(500).show().animate({ 'opacity':'1' }, 300);
        DOCK_content.delay(400).animate({ 'height': DOCK_a.outerHeight(true)+'px' }, 200);      
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfeito! Agora funcionou direitinho. Muito obrigado \o

Comment: Amigo, estou com um problema! De repente parou de funcionar. Eu adicionei mais links e mais conteúdo e eu clico no 7º link, por exemplo, e abre o conteúdo do 3º.

Comment: @Ricardo Você consegue montar um exemplo que reproduza o problema ho http://jsfiddle.net? Talvez seja o caso de postar uma pergunta nova sobre isso, mas deixa eu ver o código antes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3tvqhcys/ || Bem, não utilizei o meu html pois ele está grande, mas é semelhante. Há uma parte em que os links tem uma orientação e uma outra que os links tem outra orientação. Nesse exemplo, os últimos links não funcionam.

Comment: Entendi, @Ricardo. Como eu expliquei na resposta, o index é o índice do elemento em relação ao pai, incluindo todos os filhos do pai (não só os com a sua classe). Pelo que estou vendo, usar index não é uma boa abordagem no seu caso, sugiro algo diferente: http://jsfiddle.net/3tvqhcys/4/

Comment: Outra coisa: reparei que você tem IDs repetidos no seu HTML, isso não pode... @Ricardo

Comment: Ufa! Agora sim deu certo. Mais uma vez obrigado! Bem melhor utilizar um ID para cada conteúdo, mais organizado. Sobre ter um mesmo ID, é que eu estava apenas usando ele como uma exceção para uma outra função jQuery que uso, sei que não se deve ter dois ID iguais. Obrigado mais uma vez \o